# Why won't Ubuntu Single Sign On allow me to register?

Tags: single-sign-on

Every time I try to register, I fill out the form and it comes back to me as if I had not included a password. I am including passwords that very definitely meet the requirements listed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try emptying the cache and the cookies of your Web browser.  After that, restart your web browser and it should work.

Comment: It seems to be a lost cause. No matter which browser i use, nor whether i try to register via Ubuntu One or the software center, i get the same problem. It seems like Ubuntu is, at the moment, incapable of recognizing that i've typed in a password at all. I'm running 11.10 on a Dell Latitude D820

Comment: are u not using a browser to register???? if not, try that.

Comment: Try it a few times on your own computer after a day or so.  Ubuntu's server may be down at that time.